# Possible to select different physical hosts on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup two servers that replicate data. I want to ensure HA by making sure the two EC2 instances are on separate physical hosts while still being in the same region.

Is it possible to ensure you instances are on different physical machines with EC2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows the when you create your instance you can select from 4 different availability zones.

- us-east-1a
- us-east-1b
- us-east-1c
- us-east-1d

Quoted from http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

"Availability Zones are distinct locations that are engineered to be insulated from failures in other Availability Zones and provide inexpensive, low latency network connectivity to other Availability Zones in the same Region. By launching instances in separate Availability Zones, you can protect your applications from failure of a single location."

Comment: Yes, you'll get LAN connectivity for instances in the same Region.